# Rails syntax error missing parenthasizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am getting a weird syntax error from rails that I don't understand.

GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR:

Showing /home/action/workspace/clinio/app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb where line #3 raised:

/home/action/workspace/clinio/app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':'
    ';@output_buffer.append=( image...
           ^

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
  <% @uncompletedtasks = @task if @uncompletedtasks?%>
  <li id="task_"> 
    <div><%= image_tag "26-mini-gray-checkmark.png" %> 
        <a href="<%=task_path(@uncompletedtasks)%>"> <%= @uncompletedtasks.task %> </a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb, app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/action/workspace/clinio

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__122972711486791642_46610700'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in`index'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that question mark at the end.

```
<% @uncompletedtasks = @task if @uncompletedtasks %>
```

(*the purpose of this code still eludes me, though. Why would you want overwrite `@uncompletedtasks` only if it has value?*)

Comment: sergio thanks for pointing out my obvious mistakes :) not so obvious to me!! I changed a few things thanks to you and now have it working
<% task = uncompletedtask  if uncompletedtask%>
<li id="task_<%= task.id%>"> 
 <div>
  <%= image_tag "26-mini-gray-checkmark.png" %> 
  <a href="<%= task_path(task)%>"> <%= task.task %> </a>
 </div>
</li>

Comment: @mattclar: it's my pleasure :)